# Sound icon missing in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lts, ubuntu-mate

Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS MATE. The sound icon in the top panel has suddenly disappeared.  Installed another user account and the icon shows in that account.

Tried several solutions here on AskUbuntu, nearly all were for older distributions and didn't work.  Suggestions appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to reset MATE Panel to defaults.

## * Terminal way

If you have customized (added, moved, removed) panels and/or applets then backup your current settings with

```
dconf dump /org/mate/panel/ > dconf_panel
```

Then reset them to defaults:

```
dconf reset -f /org/mate/panel/
```

---

## * GUI way

Open MATE Tweak with `mate-tweak` command, select tab *Panel* click *Save As* button, choose name for current layout (for example, *Familiar-broken*), click *OK* and then select default layout from drop-down menu again (for example, *Familiar*):

[image: MATE Tweak - Panel]

Comment: I used the GUI method and it worked, but after clicking on "Familiar", after setting a "Familiar-broken" option, it also added some un-wanted icons. After I then clicked "Familiar-broken" the original sound icon came back.  Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem in Kubuntu 18.04 (no MATE).  The problem appeared quite suddenly.